# IIS not serving some aspx pages on production

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms

I added aspx pages inside MVC project to integrate Crystal Reports. Only two of the aspx pages display when deployed to production but the rest do not. They only work on my local server even though the same steps were taken to create the aspx pages. I noticed that the javascript for other aspx pages do not get called.

I made another aspx page, a duplicate of the ones that worked, and it still did not work on production. It seems that any new aspx page added does not work at all.

I also tried %systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -i" to register IIS for ASP.Net application. It did not resolve the issue.

IIS: 10.0.14393.0 v.1607
Crystal Reports SP25 32-bit runtime engine installed on Visual Studio Professional 2017 and on server.

```
//auto-generated Javascript in aspx page
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Report_Transactions.aspx.cs" Inherits="CWTS.Webforms.Report_Transactions" %>

<%@ Register assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" tagprefix="CR" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        </div>
        <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False" EnableParameterPrompt="False" HasToggleGroupTreeButton="False" HasToggleParameterPanelButton="False" ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh="True" ToolPanelView="None" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
//code in webform (aspx page)
    public partial class Report_Transactions : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private ReportDocument report;
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //report loaded for first time and need to set up configuration to connection tables to datasource (database in this case)
            if (!IsPostBack || (ReportDocument)Session["Report"] == null)
            {
                report = new ReportDocument();
                report.Load(Server.MapPath(@"~\Reports\Transactions.rpt"));


                //automatically log in to database without prompting the user 
                Helpers.CrystalReportHelper.ConfigureCrystalReport(report);

                //remember loaded report (able to go next/previous page on the same report)
                Session.Add("Report", report);
            }

            //connect crystal report viewer from webform to display loaded report in session
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = (ReportDocument)Session["Report"];

            //prevent prompting of parameters when report is opened
            CrystalReportViewer1.EnableParameterPrompt = false;
        }
    }
```

No error message received. Loaded blank page. When I clicked on View Source, it was empty. I expected a Crystal Report Viewer to load. This worked for only two aspx pages but not for any new aspx pages.

Comment: According to your description, I couldn't find out the reason directly. I suggest you could check the F12 develop tool firstly to find if there is any error in it. Then I suggest you could tell us how you publish the new apsx page to the production environment. By using web deploy or else. Besides, I suggest you could try to use remote debug for the web application to check if the pageload event is fired [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-7-5-computer?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @BrandoZhang, I did F12 and the only thing showed up was the <html><head></head><body></body></html> without anything in it. The website was published by TFS Build & Release. What remote debug for web application would you suggest?

Comment: Okay, I found out that the .dll files in the bin folder not getting updated when built. Still not sure why that is happening though.

Comment: I suggest you could try to use web deploy to republish the application to production server or genreate a package and install it to the production server. It may work well.